# Using DateFormatter to parse this string into a Date?

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm hitting a webservice that is returning a string in the following format:

"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ"

It's very close to the standard UTC format, but just without the ss at the end. My issue is that my dateFormatter is always returning nil...and I have tried to make sure that locale and everything else is setup properly.

Here is an example of an actual string:

`2019-12-26T00:00Z`

Here is the code that creates the DF:

```
extension DateFormatter {
    @objc static func defaultDateFormat(_ format: String) -> DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "US")
        formatter.dateFormat = format
        return formatter
    }

    func date(from string: String?) -> Date? {
        if let string = string {
            return self.date(from: string)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func string(fromOptional date: Date?) -> String? {
        if let date = date {
            return self.string(from: date)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func string(fromOptional date: Date?, defaultStr: String) -> String {
        return self.string(fromOptional: date) ?? defaultStr
    }
}

let df = DateFormatter.defaultDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmZ")
let date: Date? = df.date(from: __dateString__) // always nil
```

Comment: Also it's advised to set the time zone because of problems with daylight saving time changes.

Comment: By the way, there is no locale `US`.

Comment: thanks! I've changed that but am still seeing nil everytime. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You want to use a locale of `en_US_POSIX`, an invariant locale that always works for ISO 8601 / RFC 3339 date strings. See [Technical Q&A 1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1480/_index.html).
2. If you want to use this formatter to convert a date back to a string like `2019-12-26T00:00Z`, you will want to:

   - Use `X` (or `ZZZZZ` or `XXXXX`) in your format string, not `Z` (see the “zone” section in the table at [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and you’ll see how these various time zone patterns, e.g. `Z`, `ZZZZZ`, and `X`, are interpreted); and
   - Set the `timeZone` of the formatter to use Zulu/GMT/UTC.

Thus:

```
@objc static func defaultDateFormat(_ format: String) -> DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
    formatter.dateFormat = format
    return formatter
}
```

And

```
let df = DateFormatter.defaultDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mmX")
let date = df.date(from: "2019-12-26T00:00Z")
```

Or

```
let string = df.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: Amazing! Can you help me understand the utility of 'X' and setting the timeZone as such?

Comment: Try it with `Z` and see what you get when you convert from date back to string. You’d get something like `2019-10-15T22:57+0000`, which is not what you want. See the “zone” section in the table at [Date Format Strings](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) and you’ll see how `Z`, `ZZZZZ`, and `X` are interpreted.

Comment: Re the setting of the `timeZone`, try removing that line and again see what happens when you generate a string from a date. You’ll get a string in your local timezone (e.g. without timezone, if I generate a string on my computer, it says `2019-10-15T16:02-07:00`), whereas your server is likely assuming it will be in Zulu/GMT/UTC, designated with the `Z`, not `-07:00` (or whatever your local timezone will be).